# How to compile a visual studio c++ project on linux efficiently

Tags: c++, gcc, visual-c++

I'm having a C++ Project in Visual Studio 2017 which uses curl. It compiles fine on a linux machine. But i think my procedure is not efficient. Im just copying my source files to the linux machine and run

```
g++ one.cpp two.cpp etc.cpp -lcurl
```

or even

```
g++ *.cpp -lcurl -o output
```

Is there something to do this a "cool" way? Like cmake or something (sorry im not into this).  An Example would be really helpful

Comment: There's _visual studio code_ which you can use to edit and compile visual studio projects on linux. Otherwise ditch the visual studio make buildchain, in preference to setup a reasonable GNU make based one.

Comment: If by "cool way" you mean using an IDE, then yes there are some alternatives that exists on multiple platforms. And yes you can use CMake to create projects for both Visual Studio (the full IDE) as well as other IDE's and also plain makefiles. You might want to read [the documentation](https://cmake.org/documentation/) or some tutorials.

Comment: But libraries are a pain in the ass on windows (with gnu) . With vcpkg its just like linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your options range wildly from:

- Just keep doing what you're doing
- Wrap that command in a shell script so you don't have to keep typing it
- Make a *Makefile* to auto-generate that command
- Use *CMake* to auto-generate the *Makefile* (or *automake* or something else)
- Use an IDE (examples for various platforms: *Eclipse*, *Xcode*, *Visual Studio*) to fully manage the project for you, including build rules/commands — *Visual Studio Code* in particular may be of interest here

It is completely up to you what you pick.

Personally, in your situation, right now I'd just throw together a *Makefile* and be done with it, until your needs become more complex.

Whichever of the latter 3 options you pick, there are abundant examples online and in your book already.

I would say, please don't use a really complicated solution to solve a simple problem just because it's "cool", because that's not what cool is.